Dockerizing Laravel app always fails at one particular line on alpine and debain images
I have been trying to dockerize laravel app. there is a particular line that always fail. I tried many things but it has been hours that I have been unable to find a solution. Before I used alpine based phpfpm but that also failed so switched to debian based so that it may be able to successfully process. but it didn't.
FROM php:8.3.9-fpm

RUN echo "deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye main" > /etc/apt/sources.list \
    && echo "deb http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list \
    && echo "deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list

RUN apt-get update -o Debug::pkgProblemResolver=true && apt-get install -y \
    curl \
    libpng-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    zip \
    unzip \
    libonig-dev \
    libxml2-dev \
    netcat-openbsd \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg \
    && docker-php-ext-install gd pdo pdo_mysql mbstring exif pcntl bcmath opcache \
    && docker-php-ext-enable gd mbstring exif pcntl bcmath opcache \
    && apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

 # Rest of the docker file

and this is the error I always get.
 => ERROR [stage-0 4/7] RUN apt-get update -o Debug::pkgProblemResolver=true && apt-get install -y     curl     libpng-dev     libjpeg62-turbo-dev     libfree  296.5s
------
 > [stage-0 4/7] RUN apt-get update -o Debug::pkgProblemResolver=true && apt-get install -y     curl     libpng-dev     libjpeg62-turbo-dev     libfreetype6-dev     zip     unzip     libonig-dev     libxml2-dev     netcat-openbsd     && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg     && docker-php-ext-install gd pdo pdo_mysql mbstring exif pcntl bcmath opcache     && docker-php-ext-enable gd mbstring exif pcntl bcmath opcache     && apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*:
13.49 Ign:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye InRelease
25.78 Ign:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security InRelease
38.06 Ign:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates InRelease
50.35 Ign:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm InRelease
62.64 Ign:5 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-updates InRelease
74.93 Ign:6 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security InRelease
87.21 Ign:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye InRelease
99.56 Ign:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security InRelease
111.9 Ign:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates InRelease
124.1 Ign:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm InRelease
136.4 Ign:5 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-updates InRelease
148.7 Ign:6 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security InRelease
161.0 Ign:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye InRelease
173.4 Ign:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security InRelease
185.7 Ign:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates InRelease
197.9 Ign:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm InRelease
210.2 Ign:5 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-updates InRelease
222.5 Ign:6 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security InRelease
234.8 Err:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye InRelease
234.8   Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'
247.1 Err:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security InRelease
247.1   Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'
259.4 Err:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates InRelease
259.4   Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'
271.7 Err:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm InRelease
271.7   Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'
284.0 Err:5 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-updates InRelease
284.0   Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'
296.2 Err:6 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security InRelease
296.2   Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'
296.3 Reading package lists...
296.3 W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/bullseye/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'
296.3 W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/dists/bullseye-security/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'
296.3 W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/bullseye-updates/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'
296.3 W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/bookworm/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'
296.3 W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/bookworm-updates/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'
296.3 W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/dists/bookworm-security/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'
296.3 W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
296.3 Reading package lists...
296.4 Building dependency tree...
296.4 Reading state information...
296.4 E: Unable to locate package libpng-dev
296.4 E: Unable to locate package libjpeg62-turbo-dev
296.4 E: Unable to locate package libfreetype6-dev
296.4 E: Unable to locate package zip
296.4 E: Unable to locate package unzip
296.4 E: Unable to locate package libonig-dev
296.4 E: Unable to locate package libxml2-dev
296.4 E: Unable to locate package netcat-openbsd
------
Dockerfile:14
--------------------
  13 |     
  14 | >>> RUN apt-get update -o Debug::pkgProblemResolver=true && apt-get install -y \
  15 | >>>     curl \
  16 | >>>     libpng-dev \
  17 | >>>     libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
  18 | >>>     libfreetype6-dev \
  19 | >>>     zip \
  20 | >>>     unzip \
  21 | >>>     libonig-dev \
  22 | >>>     libxml2-dev \
  23 | >>>     netcat-openbsd \
  24 | >>>     && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg \
  25 | >>>     && docker-php-ext-install gd pdo pdo_mysql mbstring exif pcntl bcmath opcache \
  26 | >>>     && docker-php-ext-enable gd mbstring exif pcntl bcmath opcache \
  27 | >>>     && apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
  28 |     
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c apt-get update -o Debug::pkgProblemResolver=true && apt-get install -y     curl     libpng-dev     libjpeg62-turbo-dev     libfreetype6-dev     zip     unzip     libonig-dev     libxml2-dev     netcat-openbsd     && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg     && docker-php-ext-install gd pdo pdo_mysql mbstring exif pcntl bcmath opcache     && docker-php-ext-enable gd mbstring exif pcntl bcmath opcache     && apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*" did not complete successfully: exit code: 100

Do you know how can I solve this issue?
